# Quandl response extremely slow on my home network as opposed to my mobile WIFI hotspot network

Tags: pandas, numpy, quandl

As stated in the question, something weird is happening.
My quandl code:

```
import quandl

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print(df.head())
```

Responds after a few minutes on my home network, however if i connect my laptop to mobile WIFI hotspot, it responds in seconds.

I am truely perplexed as to the cause of this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Quandl python module is having issues where IPV6 Protocol connectivity is supported along with IPV4. By disabling IPV6 connectivity on my ubuntu machine, the data response is prompt and normal.

Steps to disable IPV6 in ubuntu:

Edit the sysctl.conf file as follows:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Append the following lines at the bottom:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Restart the systcl.conf file or reboot:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Happy mining! =D

Comment: This worked for me on both Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: This also worked for me under `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if your network is using IPv4 or IPv6? There appears to be an issue  with IPv6 and the Quandl API lately. We are investigating

Comment: Quandl is indeed having issues where IPV6 is supported along with IPV4. Please see my answers as to how i solved it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: We are working with our provider to rectify the IPv6 issue. Will hopefully have this resolved soon.

Comment: Following up. IPv6 should now be working properly for those using www.quandl.com. If you still are having issues please be sure to reach out to support or try the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to mitigate the issue without disabling IPv6 would be to prioritize IPv4 resolution. You can configure how `getaddrinfo()` works by editing/creating `/etc/gai.conf` and giving a high precedence to the IPv4 range:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```